# C# type conversion returning child class when specifying type of base class

Tags: c#, type-conversion

When I run the following:

`ParentClass foo = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as ParentClass;`

The xml document loaded in `xmlReader` is an inherited type of `ParentClass`. When examined in the debugger, `foo` is showing as being an instance of the inherited class, not the parent class. Of course, the inherited class is also of type ParentClass, but why does the `as` keyword have this behavior? Why doesn't C# strip out all the other object information not required to convert to `ParentClass`.

This is not a problem, but more or less a question out of curiosity.

Comment: If it is a `ChildClass` then that is what you will see in the debugger, you are only casting it to a `ParentClass` not converting it, it is still a `ChildClass` and can be cast back.

Comment: Because it is actually a reference to type `ChildClass` in memory. The cast doesn't change that.

Comment: So "as" does not actually modify the object in any way? It just verifies that given a reference to an object, the inheritance structure is compatible?

Comment: Consider how dangerous it would be if you could strip off parts of any object. What would a FileStream mean that you strip down to a Stream? It cannot work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object itself is not modified, which is why the object's type is still displayed as "ParentClass" in the debugger.

Consider the following example, which I think is illustrative.  What do you think is output to the console here?

```
class Program
{
    public class ParentClass
    {
        public virtual void foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("parent.foo");
        }

        public virtual void bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("parent.bar");
        }
    }

    public class InheritedClass : ParentClass
    {
        public new void foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inherited.foo");
        }

        public override void bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inherited.bar");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inherited = new InheritedClass();
        var parent = inherited as ParentClass;
        var d = parent as dynamic;

        parent.foo();
        inherited.foo();
        d.foo();

        parent.bar();
        inherited.bar();
        d.bar();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Only one object is created, and then two more references to it are created: one with the inherited static type, and one with the "dynamic" type.  That all references refer to the same object is demonstrated by the fact that invoking "bar" invokes "InheritedClass.bar" regardless of the static type (the runtime type is always the same).

However, notice the difference between using "override" and "new": you will see that "parent.foo()" invokes the "ParentClass.foo" method.  That is because the "parent" variable is of the static type "ParentClass" type, and so the C# compiler emits IL instructions to call the method on "ParentClass".  You can see further that the "dynamic" type reference still calls "InheritedClass.foo", because dynamic types resolve at runtime, and this resolves to the actual runtime type which is "InheritedClass".

**Edit** @InBetween has an important distinction that I didn't consider.  In the case of casting from a value type to a reference type (or vice versa), a new object *is* actually created, as new memory must be allocated on the heap or stack respectively (the "boxing" process).  Of course, partly for this reason, virtual methods are not supported for `struct` and other value types.

Answer (score 1):

`as` can only perform reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. It wont perform any other type of conversions like user-defined conversions.

In your case its performing a compatible reference conversion; the object remains the same, you are only changing the reference.

But `as` can "modify" an object in the sense that I think you are saying when, for example, boxing which entails more than simply converting the reference.

```
var o = 1 as object;
```

`o` is an alltogether different object than integer `1`.

It is important to note though that in any succesful `as` conversion `GetType()` will still return the original type of the object which is *not* the general behavior of the *cast operator*.

Comment: I don't see how one could consider boxing a modification.

Comment: @usr: A reference conversion changes the *type* of the reference, but the object it is pointing to remains the same. When boxing a *value type* you are wrapping the value inside a `System.Object` and storing it *somewhere else* (managed heap although that is impementation sepcific); that means you have a reference to completely different object.

Comment: A new object is allocated and you get a reference to it. I would not consider this a modification of anything. New data was created.

Comment: @usr Yes, it *is* a modification of the reference, which changes what its pointing to. That does not happen when `as` performs a reference conversion which was the OP's question so I thought it was interesting to point out the difference. `var fooBaseType = foo as FooBaseType` doesn't change anything about where the reference is pointing at; `foo` and `fooBaseTpye` are pointing to the same exact object. That is completely different from `var boxed = someInt as object` where `someInt` and `boxed` are completely unrelated as to where and what they are pointing at. We are arguing semantics.